# How to use multiple custom post types to archive as front page?

Tags: php, custom-post-types

I am trying to modify my code to show multiple custom post types on the front page. This code works good for a single custom post type, but I can't figure out how to add a second custom post type.

How can the following code be modified to show a second custom post type?

```php
function blestrecipes_cpt_filter( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'recipes' ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'blestrecipes_cpt_filter' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looks like you've almost got it. To include multiple custom post types in the `WP_Query` object, just change:

```php
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'recipes' ) );
```

to:

```php
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'recipes', 'another-custom-post-type' ) );
```

Basically adding more elements to the array.

So the final code becomes:

```php
function blestrecipes_cpt_filter( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'recipes', 'another-custom-post-type' ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'blestrecipes_cpt_filter' );
```

Comment: That works great. Thank you.